# Who is the woman Kusanagi saw during the ferry scene?

Tags: ghost-in-the-shell

In the ferry scene in *Ghost in the Shell* (1995), Kusanagi Motoko saw a woman in a cafe that bears resemblance to her. Who is this woman? What is her significance in the scene?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Disclaimer:**  This is a very complicated movie and I don't claim to fully understand everything that happens in it.  The following is the best sense I've made of the scene in question, but there's certainly room for other interpretations, I'm sure.

I always figured this was another woman with the same body model as Kusanagi.  She mentions earlier in the film that her entire body is cybernetic, and it stands to reason that there are a finite number of models being manufactured.

The woman herself (whoever she is) is not relevant, however, Kusanagi seeing "herself" in the crowd underscores the themes of individuality and identity in a cybernetic and networked society, which the film is exploring.

Comment: Well, it was mentioned (in series IIRC) that her body was standard model, heavily modified underneath though. So it's quite possible.